# In Python Is it possible to have trace logging and normal loggin occurring at same time

Tags: python, logging, trace

I am using python trace module to trace code execution and it works fine.

However, I would like to generate normal debug/info log statements in addition to the call tracing logging. Currently, once I set sys.settrace(mytracemethod), my existing debug/info log statements do not show up, only the "Call to blah blah called from line blah blah" lines show up from the "mytracemethod" logging code.

I thought if i created two loggers with two different names...using logger.getlogger(logger_name) and set them both up correctly, but had the logger in the "mytracemethod" using a different logger than the rest of the methods, I would see different output in the two log files...but that is not the case. I get two log files, but they have the same output.

Is this even possible what I am trying to achieve?

Any advice would be appreciated by this python logging newbie!  thanks!

Comment: Have you tried logging to a file and tracing as normal?

Comment: By normal do you mean just "print" the tracing output to console? Or do you mean not use the sys.settrace(..)?